# PHP stream reading: doesn't reach EOF if I write results to a string in larger files

Tags: php

Brand new to PHP, and having a hard time of it. I'm trying to get a server response and put the contents into a string. Sounds straightforward enough, but it only works for pretty short content (the content is usually an image).

The parsing is simple enough:

```
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $data = fread($fp, 1024);
        //echo $data;
        $this->response_body .= $data;
    }
```

Now, the baffling thing is that if I uncomment that echo, the thing actually works (`$response_body` still doesn't seem to get filled, though, but at least the thing terminates correctly and doesn't time out). If I don't echo the content, eof will never be reached and the thing times out.

All this tells me currently is that there seems to be a problem when writing to response_body (a variable which only prior use in the code is (`$response_body = ""`), not when reading from the stream, and that I obviously have no idea what echo does exactly. The same thing also happens if I use `fgets()`, by the way.

So the first question is, how do I get the whole content in an object without timing out? 
And the next question would be, how do I put that content into the reply to the request that called the code in the first place (as mentioned, the content usually describes an image. It would be very nice if I could just make an `<img>` tag and let the src call my script)?

It would also be nice if this was possible without additional libraries, but I would be in a position to install extensions on the server if necessary. I just don't have much experience at it.

**Additional information:**
The script is supposed to forward an image it gets from another server. That server does not release the URL and processes the images on the fly to pixelate certain areas of the image. It also won't send the images to a browser directly. So my script should take a browser request, modify it, send it to the image server, receive the image in the reply and forward it to the browser again. I was originally using [this class](https://gist.github.com/twslankard/989974) for the request, which is where the problem occured.

Comment: Can you turn on error reporting and tell us what errors you're receiving.

Comment: Why have you got two nested whiles with exactly the same condition?  Also, you might want to look at the warnings on the PHP manual for feof.  It states some cases where feof will never return true (such as passing it an invalid handle because fopen failed, etc).

Comment: "Why have you got two nested whiles with exactly the same condition?" because I made an error while copying the code. sorry about that!

Comment: "Can you turn on error reporting and tell us what errors you're receiving."  Error reporting is on, there's nothing - just a timeout after 30 seconds.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to just do `$this -> response_body = file_get_contents ($path_to_file)` instead.  You wouldn't have to fopen, fread in a loop, check for feof, etc

Comment: @GordonM: I would love to do that, but I can't. The file is provided by another server, which doesn't give me its URL but sends it as content after doing some image processing on it.

Comment: What does your fopen call look like?  Is the remote service you're consuming running Windows?  You might be getting weird behaviour by trying to fetch data from a Windows box without using the binary flag in fopen. The manual page for fopen says that for portability you should always use the binary flag, so at worst it wouldn't do any harm to set it.

Comment: @GoronM: I'm using fsockopen, actually: $fp = fsockopen($this->host_ip, $this->port); I've updated the post with more information as to the purpose and code of the script.

Comment: OK, I did a bit of reading around and apparently feof is very unreliable with sockets as it requires the server to be well-behaved and close the connection when you get to the end of the data.  If the server doesn't the socket will remain open until it times out.  Maybe you'll be better off reading the data into a buffer and checking that it doesn't equal false instead of using feof.  `while (FALSE !== ($data = fread ($fp)) {}`

Comment: what sort of server is it you're requesting the file from. what protocol?  it's obviously not HTTP else you could just use file_get_contents or curl. ...

Comment: @GordonM: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, and also some other variations that don't rely on feof, like checking the length of $data. They all suffer the same fate. The thing only terminates if I echo $data in the loop, which is something I still can't wrap my head around. What possible influence could that have?

Comment: @Jasen: It is HTTP, but I do not receive a URL to the image. I only get the image data in the response, because the original, unmodified image is not supposed to leave the server.

Comment: If it's HTTP then it should send an eof when finished!  I tried it with www.example.com and after sending its homepage it finished with an eof that feof picked up and reported true on.  Can you talk to the guys providing the service regarding whether their server is configured to send the eof and close the connection properly?

Comment: As I said, it does work for smaller files... But I realised that the larger files are chunked. Could that have an influence? By now I am working around the problem by just echoing the contents as they are read instead of storing them and then sending them, which actually works. I'm getting the images and can display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed the chunk encoding. Chunk encoding doesn't send an EOF, and evidently you never get an empty string either. I'm not sure what actually happens, but calling fgets or fread on a chunk-encoded stream will never return false and will never return an empty string. The solution is to keep up with the chunks and terminate with the size 0 chunk. Any other check evidently does not work reliably.